# how to invoke an applescript from the lock screen?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I would like to know how to invoke an applescript from the lock screen. I am using Hammerspoon for hotkey triggering. So I am kind of thinking of automating login using hotkeys if not using hammerspoon is there anyother ways?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: If privacy/security is of no concern for you, go to System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options and set Automatic Login to On, then in Security & Privacy > General uncheck the Require Password option, and your Mac will no longer prompt you for a user password on boot/wake. **Not** something I would ever recommend, but I'd recommend trying to script it even less (without a logged in user you'd need to run such scripts as root, and what could possibly go wrong with that…).

Comment: Actually I don't want to disable password option on boot/wake. I want mac to ask , but the thing which I required is to automate inputting password on password field through applescript (possibly through hotkey triggering). Since I am not sure of how to do that, I questioned here. Am I clear?

Comment: What are expecting the user to see on the lock screen that he can double-click to run it? If no-one is logged in, which user do you expect it to run as?

Comment: The scenario is the user already logged in. When mac sleeps and awakes, and asking the user to enter password => in this point I am thinking to have an applescript to do this auto password entry work ( possibly by hotkeys)